# template instantiation with boost: pass extra arguments

Tags: c++, templates, boost, instantiation

say i have instantiations of the form

```
template void MyClass<2,typeA>::some_method() const;
```

for various combinations of template parameters.

I am trying to define a single macro with boost which would take a prefix (`void`) and a suffix `some_method() const` so that I can reuse it for explicit instantiations.

With hardcoded return type and function name, this can be done along the lines (have not tested it):

```
#define DIM (2)(3)
#define DEG (typeA)(typeB)
#define INSTANTIATEONE(_, targs) void MyClass<BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(targs)>::some_method() const;
#define INSTANTIATEALL() BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(INSTANTIATEONE, (DIM)(DEG));
```

Is there a way to extend the macro to have `void` and `some_method() const` as arguments? I am new to boost preprocessor and can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using

```
# include <boost/preprocessor/facilities/empty.hpp>
# include <boost/preprocessor/list/at.hpp>
# include <boost/preprocessor/list/for_each_product.hpp>
# include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
# include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_list.hpp>

#define DIM BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_LIST(2,(2,3))
#define DEG BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_LIST(1,(typeA))

#define INSTANTIATE(R, L) \
    template void MyClass<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, L), \
                          BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, L)>::some_method() const;                            
BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(INSTANTIATE, 2, (DIM, DEG))
```